# My Angular2 Project suddenly stopped working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Angular2 Project Which I was deploying and consuming from Ubuntu 16,But today it has stopped working,

The error it gives is that it could not load /angular2/core module.

Please help me

```
package.json
============
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",

    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you're obviusly trying to `import {...} from 'angular2/core'` somewhere. It's been '@angular/core' for some time now. Try searching your entire project for `angular2/core`.

Your package.json includes `"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15"` as a dependency. It's importing from `'angular2/core'` here https://github.com/wardbell/a2-in-memory-web-api/blob/0.1.15/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts.

Try updating `angular2-in-memory-web-api` with `npm install angular2-in-memory-web-api --save`

edit: Even that latest versino of `angular2-in-memory-web-api` uses `"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17"`. You'll either need to downgrade angular or get rid of that package.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind marking this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple of things.  Firstly, reinstall @angular.  Secondly, if that didn't work, make sure your systemJs settings are correct.

Comment: I'm new to Angular , how to reinstall @angular , will npm install help?

Comment: Change directory to your project directory containing the package.json file, then type npm install...  That will reinstall all of your packages and update any dependencies.  If the problem is a corrupt file, this should fix it.